# Unity license within release build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have Unity Pro license with Android support. When Unity makes a release build for a platform, how is that I know that build was made using my license ? How to know if someone is using a authentic license or hacked license ? Will such information be stored within the build ?

Answer (score 3):

> When Unity makes a release build for a platform, how is that I know that build was made using my license.

Literally, this question doesn't make any sense.  Unity do not need to use your license to build *their* software.  They own the IP rights to their software, and don't require anyone's Unity license to permit them to do anything.

You probably meant to ask if your license permits *you* to use a specific Unity build on a particular platform.  The answer to that would be in your license agreement with Unity.  I suggest that you read the licensing FAQs, and if that doesn't answer your question, then ask an IP lawyer to provide you with an answer.

> How to know if someone is using a authentic license or hacked license ?

You cannot tell if someone else is using a hacked license.  (And I don't see why you would need to know ... or why you have any right to know.)

How do you know if *you* are using a genuine license?  If you got it directly from Unity, then it will be genuine.  Otherwise, I guess you could ask Unity to validate your license for you ...

> Will such information be stored within the build ?

Within the release build of Unity that you are using?  No!  That's not how license mechanisms work (in general).

Comment: `Literally, this question [doesn't] make any sense` I think his question affected you too :). +1 Good post thought.